# Why is $\mathbb{E}[\vert X-Y \vert^2]=tr(\Sigma_X)+tr(\Sigma_Y)-2tr(K)$ for $X,Y$ multivariate normal random vectors?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am reading "The Fréchet distance between multivariate normal distributions" by Downson and Landau (you can find it [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X8290077X)). And they say, that for $X,Y$ multivariate normal $d$ dimensional random vectors each one centered at $0$ and with corresponding covariance matrices $\Sigma_X$ and $\Sigma_Y$. Then the $2d$ dimensional random vector $W=\left[\begin{matrix}X \\ Y\end{matrix}\right]$ will have a covariance given by $A=\left[\begin{matrix} \Sigma_X &K\\ K^T &\Sigma_Y \end{matrix}\right]$ and marginals $\mathbb{P}_X$ and $\mathbb{P}_Y$.

Then they say that clearly (which is not clear for me) that $\mathbb{E}[\vert X-Y\vert^2]=tr(\Sigma_X)+tr(\Sigma_Y)-2tr(K).$

Could someone please expand on this ... in particular explain where do the traces come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

1. $|X - Y|^2 = (X - Y)^T(X - Y) = X^TX - 2X^TY + Y^TY$.
2. $E(X^TX) = E(\mathrm{tr}(X^TX)) = E(\mathrm{tr}(XX^T)) = \mathrm{tr}(E(XX^T)) = \mathrm{tr}(\Sigma_X)$, by the property of trace: $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(BA)$.
   The remaining two terms can be evaluated analogously.

Comment: Why is $E(X^TY)=K$?

Comment: @leplata This is your assumption of $A$: check the definition of covariance matrix.

Comment: Oooo now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if $a\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $a^{\top}a=\operatorname{tr}(a^{\top}a)=\operatorname{tr}(aa^{\top})$. Then,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\|X-Y\|^2&=\mathsf{E}\operatorname{tr}\left((X-Y)^{\top}(X-Y)\right) \\
&=\mathsf{E}\operatorname{tr}\left((X-Y)(X-Y)^{\top}\right) \\
&=\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma_X)+\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma_Y)-2\operatorname{tr}(K).
\end{align}